# Using Primeng's MegaMenu component, how do I make my nested options interact with "routerLink"

Tags: angular, primeng, megamenu

thank you for taking the time to read this.

To clarify I am new to primeNg, and no master angular user either.

The menu itself is displaying nicely and operating as expected, except for the following:  I can set a top menu to respond to being clicked by following the routerLink set.  However in the menu options that create a drop down, I can't get the same behaviour of the dropped down options.

eg:

```
    this.items = [
        {
            
            label: 'Menu option', icon: 'pi pi-upload',
            items: [
                [
                    {
                        label: 'I'm not Working',
                        routerLink:['notWorking'],

                    },
                ],
                
            ]
        },
     
        {
            label: 'I am working', 
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar', 
            routerLink:["workingGreat"],

        },

    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew as soon as I asked I'd figure it out.

If anyone else is having this issue - this works :)

```json
this.items = [{
    label: 'Menu option',
    icon: 'pi pi-upload',
    items: [
        [{
            //ADD THIS HERE
            items:[{
                label: 'I'm not Working',
                routerLink:['notWorking']
            }]
        }]
    ]},
{
    label: 'I am working', 
    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar', 
    routerLink:["workingGreat"]
}]
```